# Mockito when throwing RuntimeException with no details

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

All I'm trying to do is mock the behavior of one of my mocks to return another mock.

```
@Mock
private ClassA mock1;

@Mock
private ClassB mock2;

.
.
.
when(mock1.call(any(ClassB.class))).thenReturn(mock2);
```

This code is throwing a RuntimeException with no details in the cause/stacktrace/etc. Running the debugger in Intellij shows me this

```
result = {RuntimeException@3072} Method threw 'java.lang.RuntimeException' exception.
    detailMessage = null
    cause = null
    stackTrace = null
    suppressedExceptions = null
```

Using Intellij's evaluator with breakpoints, I narrowed the part of the code that's throwing the exception down to just the mock.method

```
when(mock1.call(any(ClassB.class)));
```

Skeleton of ClassA:

```
public class ClassA {
    public ClassB call(ClassB input) {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

Fiddled around for a while but I think I'm stuck. I've used Mockito for ~2 years and have never come across this. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check if the `call` method is `final` in `ClassA`? or `static`?

Comment: It is neither. I just added the basic skeleton of ```ClassA``` in the question summary.

Comment: Are you using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` ? If not, can you try with `private ClassA mock1 = Mockito.mock(ClassA.class)` and similary for `ClassB` and see? And remove `@Mock` annotations.

Comment: Yes, I am using ```@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)```. I'm just adding to an already existing test file that has always successfully used mocks

Comment: I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work. your code looks fine to me. you can try moving just these two fields and test the mock in different test class and see if it works

Comment: can you please check if mock1 is null?

Comment: @AtulKumbhar mock1 is defined as shown by my Intellij debug evaluator. Every mock I'm using is defined

Comment: I tried using your code, and it works perfectly fine. Can you please post content of ClassA.call() ?

Comment: Is the problem persisting when you use `doReturn` instead?

Comment: Looks like it works with ```doReturn```... strange